# Trackbar Size and Values Error in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have created a trackbar in OpenCV using the following code:- But, the size of the output trackbar is very small and not according to the window size mentioned. And also, the min and max values for the trackbars are not displayed  and aslo when I scroll the trackbar no values are displayed as you can see in the attached figure. Any suggestions on how can I resolve this issue? Thanks for the help! Feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

```
# Create a Trackbar Window to detect HSV Color range

cv.namedWindow('HSV Trackbar')
cv.resizeWindow('HSV Trackbar', 640, 240)

# Define the Trackbars in the Trackbar Window

def empty(a):
    pass

cv.createTrackbar('HUE Min', 'HSV Trackbar', 0, 179, empty)
cv.createTrackbar('HUE Max', 'HSV Trackbar', 179, 179, empty)
cv.createTrackbar('Sat Min', 'HSV Trackbar', 0, 255, empty)
cv.createTrackbar('Sat Max', 'HSV Trackbar', 255, 255, empty)
cv.createTrackbar('Val Min', 'HSV Trackbar', 0, 255, empty)
cv.createTrackbar('Val Max', 'HSV Trackbar', 255, 255, empty)
```

[image]

Comment: did you call `waitKey` at all?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes I did!

Comment: resizeWindow() resizes the *client area* of the window, which means the size of the picture that is shown... since you don't show a picture, the resize operation is meaningless. a window without a picture is an "unusual" case. I guess you could submit it as a bug/feature request to OpenCV on their github.